# Game maker - Object will not slow down

Tags: game-physics, game-maker

The object rotates and then goes forward in the direction it is facing
 but it will not slow down.  The code below shows the code which handles the speed. image_angle is defined in the previous code. sp is the current speed and mxsp is the max speed.

```
if (sp > mxsp) sp = mxsp;
sp = max(sp - 1,0)
if (up =! 0) motion_add(image_angle,sp)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your code:

```
if (sp > mxsp) sp = mxsp;
sp = max(sp - 1,0)
```

you can change it to

```
sp = median(0, mxsp, sp - 1);
```

Here:

```
if (up =! 0) motion_add(image_angle,sp)
```

not understand what is `up`. Must be `sp`, as I understand.

`=!` is incorrect, must be `!=`

`=! 0` always is `true` (`= !0`, same with `= 1`), so it always will add motion.